# Jenkins Dependent build for common branch

Tags: jenkins

I have a requirement to do a dependent build using Jenkins Following is the requirement:

1. Project 1 has a branch which is used among two release lines. For example project1 development branch ikt/master is share in two release line rel1.2_4GB and rel_1.2_2JB.
2. When ever a change is submitted in ikt/master of project1 it should trigger build of both the release line rel1.2_4GB and rel_1.2_2JB simultaneously.
3. Build results should wait for other build to pass means both builds should be green.

Please suggest me steps using both plugin as well as without plugin (if possible).

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to do this.

It's very simple and easy to use and you can trigger several child jobs and wait for their results. Based on their results, you can choose to fail or pass the build.

I suggest you read some more about it and do some experimenting. It works very well for me.

I hope this helps.

**NOTE** - I suggest not wasting time looking for a non plugin solution. If you have a good tool, use it. Don't loose time trying to be smarter...